# Stop alexa switching tv to fire tv

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I've just started using Fire TV and it's great.

Is there anyway to stop it switching the tv to firestick when you press the alexa micraphone button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off HDMI CEC under the Fire TV's Display settings.

Comment: Thanks Elias, that did it